# What happens when a frame of reference oscillates with a spinning electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

If a spinning electron was oscillating back and forth, it would create a magnetic field. If I were to hypothetically oscillate with it, it would appear stationary. So, would I experience its magnetic field, or is there a fundamental flaw with the scenario?

Comment: Maxwell's equations are invariant under Lorentz boosts, i.e. you can boost into reference frame that is inertial. What you want is a reference frame that is not inertial. In it Maxwell's equations could be very different, so your expectations, based on inertial reference frames, would not apply (granted Earth is not quite inertial)